# CSS formatting for multi-column associative array

Tags: php, css, textbox, associative-array, word-wrap

I'm trying to make the following PHP function work in a CSS scrolling text box with word wrap (this is the entire program example--there is no other CSS).

```
<?php

    function prettyPrint( $my_array ) {

    if (is_array($my_array)) {

        echo "<table style=border=0 cellspacing=2 cellpadding=1 width=100%>";
        echo '<tr><td colspan=2 style="background-color:#B29980;"></td></tr>';

        foreach ($my_array as $k => $v) {
            if (is_int($k)){$k=$k+1;}                    
            echo '<tr><td valign="top" style="width:20px;background-color:#F0F0F0;">';
            echo '<strong>' . "&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $k . "&nbsp;&nbsp;" . "</strong></td><td>";
            prettyPrint( $v ) ;
            echo "</td></tr>";
        }

        echo '<tr><td colspan=2 style="background-color:#B29980;"></td></tr>';
        echo "</table>";
        return;
    }

    echo $my_array;
}

$array = array( array ( "Txt1" => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
                        "Txt2" => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
                array ( "Txt3" => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
                        "Txt4" => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
prettyPrint($array); 

?>
```

I had tried adding this at line 3:

```
echo '<div style="height:250px; width:980px; overflow:auto; overflow-x: hidden">';
```

This div tag added a big gap of space between grouped items and also didn't word wrap. How can I take the function's output and have it displayed in a scrolling text box that word wraps?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: seems more of a css question to me. please edit your question, add the ccd and re-tag it, will get you more answers, I guess.

Comment: Thank you, michi. I rewrote it.

Comment: including your CSS will help. plus, deleting the php/assoc-array-tags will help, too, to attract the CSS gurus who don't care about PHP. As far as I can see, this is a CSS problem, PHP and associative arrays have nothing to do with it except delivering the content.

Comment: Thanks, michi. I'm very new at this. What you're saying about the CSS is actually my problem because the original function formatted nicely without any other CSS. In fact, the example above is the complete program (which I've now clarified). I appreciate your input, michi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want the `<div>`- Container around everything, right?

Like...

```
____________ this is the <div> ________________
|                                              |
| inside here is the nested table              |
| with text 1 to text 4                        |
|______________________________________________|
```

Then go:

```
echo '<div style="height:250px; width:980px; overflow:auto; overflow-x: hidden">';
prettyPrint($array);
echo '</div>';
```

Your function prettyPrint is recursive, meaning getting called from itself several times. If you include the `<div>` within there, you will end up with several `<div>`-Containers within a nested table, which is a mess.

Comment: Michi, your answer nailed it with one try. Awesome. You are correct: it was because I'd added the <div> inside the recursive function that it was getting wrecked. Adding the <div> at the function call, itself, fixed it in two seconds. I just ran 3,000 records with over 100K words your way and it ran without a hitch. Thank you very much for your time, consideration, and help rephrasing the issue. :)